# Getting "Process exit code: 2" when running installed Python script in Inno Setup

Tags: python, inno-setup

How to run Python `setup.py libraries` in Inno Setup? I mean which section is the correct place and how to do? In general, in the terminal the following syntax works

```
python setup.py install
```

But, the following code is not working in Inno Setup `[Run]` section. **I am getting "Exit code 2"**.

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\python.exe"; \
    Parameters: "{app}\requests-master\setup.py install"; \
    WorkingDir: "{app}"; Flags: waituntilterminated
```

**LOG info as follows:**

```
[12:21:24.240] -- Run entry -- 
[12:21:24.241] Run as: Current user 
[12:21:24.242] Type: Exec 
[12:21:24.243] Filename: msiexec.exe 
[12:21:24.246] Parameters: /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Project\python-3.4.3.msi" TARGETDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Project\Python34" /passive 
[12:21:24.955] Process exit code: 0 
[12:21:24.971] -- Run entry -- 
[12:21:24.972] Run as: Current user 
[12:21:24.987] Type: Exec 
[12:21:24.988] Filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Project\Python34\python.exe 
[12:21:24.989] Parameters: C:\Program Files (x86)\Project\waitress-master\setup.py install 
[12:21:25.113] Process exit code: 2
```

Any pointers would be helpful to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `{app}` path (`C:\Program Files (x86)`) contains spaces, you have to wrap it to double-quotes (and you have to [double them to escape them in the Inno Setup script](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=params), which uses double-quotes on its own):

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\python.exe"; \
    Parameters: """{app}\requests-master\setup.py"" install"; \
    WorkingDir: "{app}"; Flags: waituntilterminated
```